# storing and restoring a snapshot of an ironruby engine

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling, ironruby

**Setup**: I am using IronRuby 1.1.3 hosted in a C# Program targeted at .NET 4.0 from VS2010.

**Goal**: In order to be able to store and resume my (rather small) application, I am looking for a way to simply store and load the entire state of my hosting engine - which is exactly a common practice for virtual machines.

**Issues**
1. Firstly, I tried to do this from within Ruby, using Marshal.dump on a "top level" object that basically has references to everything else in my code. Dumping seemingly works with no problems (I get a small 31k file).

However, upon trying to load the file, I get an exception "Class Proc does not have a valid constructor". Checking up on the Marshal class, I find that I has more limits than I care for. In particular
- an instance of MatchData, Data, Method, UnboundMethod, Proc, Thread, ThreadGroup, Continuation
* objects which defines singleton methods

Unfortunately, I am enjoying the freedom of Ruby and am using Procs and singleton methods quite extensively. What is strange to me is that I get the error not before de-serialization.

1. Secondly, I started checking if ScriptEngine and related classes might have support for storing states, etc. It seems that CompiledCode might be stored (did not try it, though), but since I don't see how the current engine state could be turned into code, this did not help me, either.
2. Furthermore, I found this approach, where a SerializableProc is defined (I might consider re-coding all my procs; but I am not sure if I manage to deal with singleton methods in the same way)
   http://rubyquiz.com/quiz38.html

   Still, I would naturally prefer an "out of the box" solution. I am also curious why Ruby does not simply take such an approach to begin with and wraps the "unmarshalable" constructs like this (besides the point, but I am curious).
3. By the way, I also stumbled upon this, which as such does not help me, but I am in that position that I actually *do* want to store "everything". Maybe this gives someone an idea ...
   http://yehudakatz.com/2011/11/19/how-to-marshal-procs-using-rubinius/

EDIT: 5. The most obvious approach, simply using the binary serializer (BinaryFormatter), does not work either; I get the error that the ScriptEngine is not marked as serializable. Still, such a kind of "brute force" solution would already solve my problem.

**Question:** How can I simply store my runtime engine? I do not actually care if from within Ruby or from the DLR. Any solution that gets this job done is greatly appreciated!

(As I do not modify the Procs or singleton methods during program runtime, I would also be happy if I could simply "merge" the changes (variable values incl. references to other objects) over the start-up state of my code.)

EDIT: since this received no answers at all, I decided to update the title. I hope the new one is catcher at states my problem better.

Comment: Seeing my question only got few visits, and no response at all, I would appreciate any help in at least rephrasing it. I was hoping my problem to be stated clearly, but not getting at least any "not possible" or the like, I am wondering how to improve the question.